# Properly cancelling kotlin coroutine job

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm scratching my head around properly cancelling coroutine job.
Test case is simple I have a class with two methods:

```
class CancellationTest {
   private var job: Job? = null
   private var scope = MainScope()

   fun run() {
      job?.cancel()
      job = scope.launch { doWork() }
   }

   fun doWork() {
      // gets data from some source and send it to BE
   }
}
```

Method `doWork` has an api call that is `suspending` and respects `cancellation`.

In the above example after counting objects that were successfully sent to backend I can see many duplicates, meaning that `cancel` did not really `cancel` previous invocation.

However if I use snippet found on the internet

```
internal class WorkingCancellation<T> {
    private val activeTask = AtomicReference<Deferred<T>?>(null)
    suspend fun cancelPreviousThenRun(block: suspend () -> T): T {
        activeTask.get()?.cancelAndJoin()

        return coroutineScope {
            val newTask = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
                block()
            }

            newTask.invokeOnCompletion {
                activeTask.compareAndSet(newTask, null)
            }

            val result: T

            while (true) {
                if (!activeTask.compareAndSet(null, newTask)) {
                    activeTask.get()?.cancelAndJoin()
                    yield()
                } else {
                    result = newTask.await()
                    break
                }
            }

            result
        }
    }
}
```

It works properly, objects are not duplicated and sent properly to BE.
One last thing is that I'm calling `run` method in a `for loop` - but anyways I'm not quire sure I understand why `job?.cancel` does not do its job properly and `WorkingCancellation` is actually working

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: cancellation only works out-of-the box if you call suspending library functions. Non-suspending code needs manual checks to make it cancellable.

Cancellation in Kotlin coroutines is cooperative, and requires the job being cancelled to check for cancellation and terminate whatever work it's doing. If the job doesn't check for cancellation, it can quite happily carry on running forever and never find out it has been cancelled.

Coroutines automatically check for cancellation when you call built-in suspending functions. If you look at the docs for commonly-used suspending functions like [`await()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html) and [`yield()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html), you'll see that they always say "This suspending function is cancellable".

Your `doWork` isn't a `suspend` function, so it can't call any other suspending functions and consequently will never hit one of those automatic checks for cancellation. If you do want to cancel it, you will need to have it periodically check whether the job is still active, or change its implementation to use suspending functions. You can manually check for cancellation by calling [`ensureActive`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/ensure-active.html) on the `Job`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Sam's answer, consider this example that mocks a continuous transaction, lets say location updates to a server.

```
var pingInterval = System.currentTimeMillis()
job = launch {
     while (true) {
         if (System.currentTimeMillis() > pingInterval) {
             Log.e("LocationJob", "Executing location updates... ")
             pingInterval += 1000L
         }
     }
}
```

Continuously it will "ping" the server with location udpates, or like any other common use-cases, say this will continuously fetch something from it.

Then I have a function here that's being called by a button that cancels this `job` operation.

```
fun cancel() {
    job.cancel()
    Log.e("LocationJob", "Location updates done.")
}
```

When this function is called, the `job` is cancelled, however the operation keeps on going because nothing ensures the coroutine scope to stop working, all actions above will print

```
 Ping server my location...
 Ping server my location...
 Ping server my location...
 Ping server my location...
 Location updates done.
 Ping server my location...
 Ping server my location...
```

Now if we insert `ensureActive()` inside the infinite loop

```
while (true) {
     ensureActive()
     if (System.currentTimeMillis() > pingInterval) {
          Log.e("LocationJob", "Ping server my location... ")
           pingInterval += 1000L
     }
}
```

Cancelling the `job` will guarantee that the operation will stop. I tested using `delay` though and it guaranteed total `cancellation` when the `job` it is being called in is cancelled. Emplacing `ensureActive()`, and cancelling after 2 seconds, prints

```
 Ping server my location...
 Ping server my location...
 Location updates done.
```